# Nullpointer Exception when sending string arrays through intent

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent, nullpointerexception

So in my android app a user signs in on main activity, then they go on to home activity and carry out the apps main function. This activity creates a list of strings that is sent through an intent when the user clicks the logout button. I convert the list to an array, before I send it through the intent. Then on my main activity there is another button "Retrieve Data" which launches another actvity, it's just a ListView though. So I want to feed the string array on again to retrieve data so the user can click on the butoon and see the list data. 
Here's where I'm sending the string array from first:

```
btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                String[] resultsArray = new String[userResults.size()];
                Intent intentLogout=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                intentLogout.putExtra("Results", resultsArray);
                startActivity(intentLogout);
            }
            });
```

Here's how I receive that and send it on again in my main Activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
         if(extras!=null)
         {
            results = extras.getStringArray("Results");
         }
         else
         {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data to retrieve yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

 btnRetrieveData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intentRD=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RetrieveDataActivity.class);
                intentRD.putExtra("UserResults", results);
                startActivity(intentRD);
            }
            });
```

And here's my retrieveDataActivity, I haven't used Listviews much before so I'm not sure if I'm making any obvious/silly mistakes:

```
public class RetrieveDataActivity extends Activity 
{
    String [] values;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listviewexampleactivity);

        // Get ListView object
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
         if(extras!=null)
         {
            values = extras.getStringArray("UserResults");
         }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

        // ListView Item Click Listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
              {

                   // ListView Clicked item index
                   int itemPosition = position;

                   // ListView Clicked item value
                   String  itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    // Show Alert 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();

              }

         }); 
    }

}
```

And finally the logcat:

```
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254): Process: com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker, PID: 28254
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-14 04:59:36.396: E/AndroidRuntime(28254):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check that your `array` is `null`.

Comment: remain to initialize something gives you this error

Comment: do you debug the app??

Comment: i think '@Sree' is right

Comment: the array is it populated with items??

Comment: I feel really stupid now, I wasn't moving the elements from my list into the array properly :/

Answer (score 1):

ok ,the problem is where you are getting the array list from the **Intent**

try

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 values=extras.getStringArrayExtra("UserResults");

intent.putExtra("Arrays",values);
```

instead of

```
values = extras.getStringArray("UserResults");
```